# Shopify / Liquid - Find FULL URL using only liquid, not Javascript

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am wondering if there is a way to get the **full** URL using only liquid (Shopify templating language). I know there are the below provided but none of them (even combined) seem to achieve it. It can be done with javascript using `window.location.href`, but I am wondering if there is a liquid-only method. For my use having to combine javascript in with my liquid makes it become a lot more complicated, hence my question.

```
{{ page.url }}
{{ shop.url }}
{{ shop.domain }}
{{ collection.url }}
{{ product.url }}
{{ blog.url }}
{{ article.url }}
{{ article.comment_post_url }}
{{ canonical_url }}
```

For instance, if my URL was [www.website.com/blogs/myblog/tagged/?123](http://www.website.com/blogs/myblog/tagged/?123) and I wanted the entire URL, including the ?123. The answer may be no, but this would seem pretty daft given they have all of the below options but not simply one for the entire URL. In my case I am going directly to the URL in the form of a href, so it is not a problem that liquid is only being applied on page load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the one of odd method to get the values from the query string of URL, but it comes with some coding working, you can it using this [link](https://freakdesign.com.au/blogs/news/get-the-url-querystring-values-with-liquid-in-shopify)

Comment: Annoying that Shopify forces such a work-around just to get params. But, that solution is working very nicely for me.

Comment: I can't update my comment above. Just for anyone using this, be aware that Shopify caches `contentForQuerystring` which the method above uses to get the params. In your dev theme, I think Shopify has caching disabled. So, will look like it's all working, when you put it in prod, you'll find revisiting the page will use the wrong param. This is due to Shopify not updating `contentQuerystring` on every page load. Unfortunately, this is the only way to get params in Liquid. So, you gotta either be okay with that issue, or move the logic into the browser with javascript.